# How to setup Kaldi on Mac?

Tags: macos, kaldi

I have gone through the official documentation of kaldi, it is very hard  to understand. can anyone suggest me a good tutorial which discribes how to run kaldi on mac??

Answer (score 2):

You can use [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/alphacep/kaldi-ru).
It fully crossplatform.

Answer (score 1):

A detailed tutorial from early 2016 on installing kaldi with a lively discussion is available here: http://jrmeyer.github.io/asr/2016/01/26/Installing-Kaldi.html